# Scraping data from a XHR with request

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, request

I want to scrape the data [of this website](https://simuladores.bancosantander.es/SantanderES/loansimulatorweb.aspx?por=webpublica&prv=publico&m=100&cta=1&ls=0#/t0). But the results I get are different from those posted on the website. For example, when I run the code, for 14000 and a duration of 48 months I get 7.03 for the TAE while the value on the site is 6.44. I think the params is wrongly set. Could someone help me?

I changed the params in several ways without it working. I do not know how to find the right params.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

#Let's first collect few auth vars
r = requests.Session()
response = r.get("https://simuladores.bancosantander.es/SantanderES/loansimulatorweb.aspx?por=webpublica&prv=publico&m=100&cta=1&ls=0#/t0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html')
key = soup.find_all('script',text=re.compile('Afi.AfiAuth.Init'))
pattern = r"Afi.AfiAuth.Init\((.*?)\)"

WSSignature = re.findall(pattern,key[0].text)[0].split(',')[-1].replace('\'','')
WSDateTime = re.findall(pattern,key[0].text)[0].split(',')[1].replace('\'','')

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://simuladores.bancosantander.es',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'WSSignature': WSSignature,
    'Referer': 'https://simuladores.bancosantander.es/SantanderES/loansimulatorweb.aspx?por=webpublica&prv=publico&m=100&cta=1&ls=0',
    'WSDateTime': WSDateTime,
    'WSClientCode': 'SantanderES',
}

#Those are the standard params of a request
params = {'wsInputs': {'finality': 'prestamo coche',
  'productCode': 'p100',
  'capitalOrInstallment': 5000,
  'monthsTerm': 96,
  'mothsInitialTerm': 12,
  'openingCommission': 1.5,
  'minOpeningCommission': 60,
  'financeOpeningCommission': True,
  'interestRate': 5.5,
  'interestRateReferenceIndex': 0,
  'interestRateSecondaryReferenceIndex': 0,
  'interestRateSecondaryWithoutVinculation': 6.5,
  'interestRateSecondaryWithAllVinculation': 0,
  'interestRateSecondary': 6.5,
  'loanDate': '2019-06-13',
  'birthDate': '2001-06-13',
  'financeLoanProtectionInsurance': True,
  'percentageNotaryCosts': 0.003,
  'loanCalculationMethod': 0,
  'calculationBase': 4,
  'frecuencyAmortization': 12,
  'frecuencyInterestPay': 12,
  'calendarConvention': 0,
  'taeCalculationBaseType': 4,
  'lackMode': 0,
  'amortizationCarencyMonths': 0,
  'typeAmortization': 1,
  'insuranceCostSinglePremium': 0,
  'with123': False,
  'electricVehicle': False}}
#The scraping function
def scrape(amount, duration, params):

    params['wsInputs']['capitalOrInstallment'] = amount
    params['wsInputs']['monthsTerm'] = duration
    response = r.post('https://simuladores.bancosantander.es/WS/WSSantanderTotalLoan.asmx/Calculate', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
    return json.loads(response.content)['d']


Amounts = [13000]
Durations = [ 48, 60, 72, 84, 96]
results = []
for amount in Amounts:
    for duration in Durations:
        result = scrape(amount, duration, params)
        result['Amount'] = amount
        result['Duration'] = duration
        results.append(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: **Mod Note:** Keep the discussion relevant to the question. If any users have issues, raise a flag or post on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Do not discuss each other here or threaten other users.

Comment: @keepAlive do not comment under this user's posts or the answers under this user's posts. This is an unofficial mod warning. If it continues it will become official.

Answer (score 2):

First, as said by @Richard, there is nothing wrong with your code.

The reason why you get 7.03% instead of 6.44% is because the loan simulator that you are using somehow cheats (to appear more competitive). The difference you have lies in the consideration of the *Comisión de apertura financiada*. This means that if you set the standard parameter `'openingCommission'` to 0, you will get *6.45%*. What about getting exactly *6.44%*? A suggestion follows.

---

Explanation (*using french terminology*)

If I compute the TEG and the TAE asociated to the hyperparameter {14k€, 48months, 330.47€/m}, I get **6.26%** and **6.44%**.

But if I do the same calculation, including the *Comisión de apertura financiada* of *210€*, I get **~7.03%** and **7.23%**.

[image]

where *i* above (and below) stands fot the [internal rate of return (IRR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return), i.e. the rate that annulates equation (E1):

[image]

---

Which means that you should consider integrating an IRR-solver within your workflow, using the available pieces of information (mensualities, duration, total amount and even fees) to recompute the TAE.